# Как проитерировать двумерный массив и сравнивая друг с другом

Tags: python, циклы, list

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть два списка с подсписками Python: 
[[2,4],[4,2],[5,8]] и [[1,2],[5,6],[2,3]]

Объясните, пожалуйста, как пройтись по этим спискам так, чтобы бралось два элемента, и относительно них как-то обрабатывались все остальные(например передавать их по одному в функцию).
Фото для наглядности.

Код:

```
blackDots = [[2, 4, 0],[3,6,0],[1,5,0],[4,7,0]];
whiteDots = [[2,3,0],[1,2,0],[4,3,0],[2,7,0]];
```

пока додумался только до такого:

```
for i in range(0, len(blackDots)-1):
  for j in range(1, len(blackDots)):
    for k in range(0, i+j):
      print(getSignFromEquation(
        blackDots[i],blackDots[j],blackDots[k])
      )
```

P.S: На третий элемент подсписков не обращайте внимание, это для записи состояния.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого в python есть встроенные функции комбинаторики, в твоем случае нужна комбинация списка, данная функция находится в модуле `itertools`

### Например:

```
from itertools import combinations

black_dots = [[2, 4, 0], [3, 6, 0], [1, 5, 0], [4, 7, 0]];
white_dots = [[2, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0], [4, 3, 0], [2, 7, 0]];

# Чтобы получить комбинацию из пар(2) только белых/черных точек
# для примера взял комбинацию только черных
for combination_of_black_dots in combinations(black_dots, 2):
    print(combination_of_black_dots)
""" Output
([2, 4, 0], [3, 6, 0])
([2, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0])
([2, 4, 0], [4, 7, 0])
([3, 6, 0], [1, 5, 0])
([3, 6, 0], [4, 7, 0])
([1, 5, 0], [4, 7, 0])
"""

# Если нужна комбинация пар(2) и белых и черных точек
# то связываем списки в одно единое
all_dots = black_dots + white_dots
for combination_of_all_dots in combinations(all_dots, 2):
    print (combination_of_all_dots)
```

Comment: Не так. Нужно взять попарно все элементы первого списка и к ним в тройку засовывать все остальные элементы из первого и второго списков. Т.е берем [2,4], сначала к нему в пару передается [3,6]. Потом эта "пара" должна пройтись по всем остальным элементам, т.е [1,5],[4,7], [2,3],... Потом в пару к [2,4] должен передаться [1,5], и эта пара делает то же самое.

Comment: А все, понял, щааа обновлю ответ)

Comment: @terequell Z Я обновил ответ, посмотри, думаю то что тебе нужно

Comment: Да там все очень просто, я обновил ответ)

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду думать :)